# Migration from AWS Aurora to AWS Aurora

Tags: database-migration, amazon-aurora

We were planning to migrate from local Oracle database to AWS Aurora(Posgres) in my customer's AWS account with AWS DMS, but my customer told us they don't know whether AWS DMS is allowed to use or not in their AWS account(due to their company rule).
So, we are planning to do follow action in case of AWS DMS is impossible.

First: Migrate from local Oracle database to AWS Aurora(Posgres) in our AWS account with AWS DMS.
Second: Migrate from AWS Aurora(Posgres) in our AWS account to AWS Aurora(Posgres) in my customer's AWS account.

I tried searching how to migrate, but could't find the answer.
Does anyone know the idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your architecture works.

I believe that you won't have any problem with the first step.

But for the second one, you have the following options:

- If your AWS account can connect to your customer AWS Aurora, you can use DMS in your account to migrate your database.
- If your AWS account can't connect to your customer AWS Aurora, you can create a dump file, send it to your customer and restore the dump in their account.